# Google Apps Script-How to get value from XmlDocument?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get all calender details of all users. I got this successfully but its return result in Xml format as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/email-id/private/full</id>
  <updated>2012-02-15T15:34:49.000Z</updated>
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event"/>
  <title type="text">email-id</title>
  <subtitle type="text">email-id</subtitle>
  <link href="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=email-id" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>
  <link href="https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/email-id/private/full" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" type="application/atom+xml"/>
  <link href="https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/email-id/private/full" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post" type="application/atom+xml"/>
  <link href="https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/email-id/private/full/batch" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch" type="application/atom+xml"/>
  <link href="https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/email-id/private/full?max-results=25" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"/>
  <author>
    <name>Name</name>
    <email>email-id</email>
  </author>
  <generator uri="http://www.google.com/calendar" version="1.0">Google Calendar</generator>
  <openSearch:totalResults xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/">1</openSearch:totalResults>
  <openSearch:startIndex xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/">1</openSearch:startIndex>
  <openSearch:itemsPerPage xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/">25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
  <gCal:timezone value="Europe/Dublin" xmlns:gCal="http://schemas.google.com/gCal/2005"/>
  <gCal:timesCleaned value="0" xmlns:gCal="http://schemas.google.com/gCal/2005"/>

  <entry>
    <id>http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/email-id/private/full/vj39u2qedgphrp10nah92h6ho0</id>
    <published>2012-02-15T11:21:54.000Z</published>
    <updated>2012-02-15T11:21:54.000Z</updated>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event"/>
    <title type="text">Test Appointment</title>
    <content type="text">This is a test description</content>
    <link href="https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dmozOXUycWVkZ3BocnAxMG5haDkyaDZobzAgcmFoaW1AZGFtc2" rel="alternate" title="alternate" type="text/html"/>
...

  </entry>
  </feed>
```

I want to get the value of title and content.Please share me with the solution
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built-in Xml service https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_xml.
With this sevice you can parse thru the xml document.